# Counting number of multiplications and additions in exponential function exp(.)

Tags: computational-complexity, elementary-functions

Existing works have evaluated the computational complexity of $\exp$ function using the big-$O$ operation. For example, the paper "On the complexity of familiar functions and numbers" by Borwein specified the complexity as $O(\log^3 n)$.

Is it possible to explicitly count the number of multiplications and additions that are used to compute $\exp(\cdot)$, rather than the big-$O$ approximation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course: if you are using a particular algorithm to compute $\exp(x)$ for a given $x$ to within a given tolerance $\epsilon$, you can go through it step by step and explicitly count each multiplication and addition you perform.  If you want a closed-form formula in terms of $x$ and $\epsilon$, that might be more difficult, depending on the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are there any papers considering this closed-form formula if a particular algorithm is given? I am looking for the formula to compare two different algorithms for a given x and $\epsilon$. I found some papers like "On the complexity of familiar functions and numbers", but I cannot locate it.